# Insert query with records exceeds the limit

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, dump

Warning: POST Content-Length of 33797274 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown on line 0

I exported the content of a mysql table and want to import it to a database with the same name as source in my local computer using PHPMyadmin but I get this error when I want to import a dump file.

Does it mean the file size is too large or what?
Is there any way arround I could do about this?

Comment: do you have access to tools like scp and mysql-client for your server? and yes, your file is to huge.

Comment: No.. I dont have access to them..!

Answer (score 1):

Since your dump file is to huge to be transfered like this (some server setting), you can use the following approach:

- dump the structure of the table (without data).
- `select` chunks of specific size of the data; each chunk smaller than 8MB.
- load the structure dump and then load the data (in correct order)

this procedure may ruin references to this table and it's data sets.

Answer (score 0):

There's usually a limit on PHPMyAdmin regarding SQL uploads.

Easiest Way - separate that SQL file into multiple files.

Other ways -

1. Try GZip.
2. Editing your php.ini file on your server and
   increase your post_max_size and upload_max_filesize.
3. Using command line always works. You will need to upload the SQL file to your remote host for this to work.

   mysql -u myuser -p mydatabase < myfile.sql